# Generating fast color rectangles

Tags: algorithm, qt, qt4, real-time, color-picker

I am designing a more powerful color picker for Qt and looking for some advice. How would one go about generating fast real-time color rectangles such as the ones found in Photoshop (for HSB and RGB). I was originally thinking of using QImage and scanline to calculate all the pixels individually but this would probably be too slow.

I was thinking it would be better to write an OpenGL shader. As I can recall you can assign colors to vertices and it would interpolate the changes for you. I just have no idea how this would be done in Qt or if this is even worth the effort.

I am using `QGraphicsView` to display the rectangle. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I am completely new to Qt but would setting a gradient as a brush not help?  I may be completely missing the point :)

Comment: As far as I know QGradient only works with 1D. I would need a 2D Gradient to do what I need.

Comment: would it really be too slow?  scanline is just a pointer to the image.  there's not a lot of overhead.  how are gradients implemented?

Comment: "Probably too slow"? Did you try? Otherwise its premature optimization. How many do color rects do you want to paint? Do you need smooth zooming? Depending on the platform, it might be too slow if you create the image via QImage in paint() over and over again. Then create it once and cache it as QPixmap, and paint just that in paint().

Answer (score 0):

Ok so looking into QGradients a bit more could you not use multiple QGradient to create the effect you need?

For the last of the 3 examples you could create a single gradient with multiple stops for the colours themselves then overlay this with a QGradient of black (alpha 0) to black (alpha 255) with apropriate stops to get the gradient to come in at the right point.